# Android 5.1 & Group SMS in Messenger defaults to MMS

Tags: sms, mms, 5.1-lollipop

Am I right in thinking that as of Lollipop 5.1 all group messages sent via Messenger are sent via MMS?

In prior versions I had the choice to send them as multiple SMS messages, which is what I want as my contract gives me unlimited SMS messages but charges me per MMS.

Comment: I noticed it as well and it really frustrates me, because MMS is barely affordable. I doubt however, that it is related to 5.1. I believe the OS update coincided with an update to the Messenger app - apparently a favor to the carriers, who can now charge us for something that is actually free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recommended the [Textra app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=en_GB) to send group SMS as an actual SMS rather than MMS and I would recommend it to everyone else too. Cost me something like 60p after the trial period ran out, or about the same as 2 MMS messages!

Answer (score 0):

-Open the stock sms app

-Open the menu

-Click on settings

-Scroll down to "MMS"

-Uncheck "SMS/MMS send to groups" (My language is german, so there is possibly a different test)

Working with CyanogenMod 5.1.1

regards
Lukas